# Can not start wifi with systemd

Tags: linux, wifi, systemd, wpa-supplicant, netctl

With command `netctl start wlp3s0-tian` got error.

```
Apr 29 18:28:57 ArchPad systemd[1]: Starting Networking for netctl profile wlp3s0-tian...
Apr 29 18:28:57 ArchPad network[1019]: Starting network profile 'wlp3s0-tian'...
Apr 29 18:29:13 ArchPad network[1019]: WPA association/authentication failed for interface 'wlp3s0'
Apr 29 18:29:13 ArchPad network[1019]: Failed to bring the network up for profile 'wlp3s0-tian'
Apr 29 18:29:13 ArchPad systemd[1]: netctl@wlp3s0\x2dtian.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
Apr 29 18:29:13 ArchPad systemd[1]: Failed to start Networking for netctl profile wlp3s0-tian.
Apr 29 18:29:13 ArchPad systemd[1]: netctl@wlp3s0\x2dtian.service: Unit entered failed state.
Apr 29 18:29:13 ArchPad systemd[1]: netctl@wlp3s0\x2dtian.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Apr 29 18:30:52 ArchPad systemd[1]: Starting Networking for netctl profile wlp3s0-tian...
Apr 29 18:30:52 ArchPad network[1672]: Starting network profile 'wlp3s0-tian'...
Apr 29 18:31:08 ArchPad network[1672]: WPA association/authentication failed for interface 'wlp3s0'
Apr 29 18:31:08 ArchPad network[1672]: Failed to bring the network up for profile 'wlp3s0-tian'
Apr 29 18:31:08 ArchPad systemd[1]: netctl@wlp3s0\x2dtian.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
Apr 29 18:31:08 ArchPad systemd[1]: Failed to start Networking for netctl profile wlp3s0-tian.
Apr 29 18:31:08 ArchPad systemd[1]: netctl@wlp3s0\x2dtian.service: Unit entered failed state.
Apr 29 18:31:08 ArchPad systemd[1]: netctl@wlp3s0\x2dtian.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Apr 29 18:31:33 ArchPad systemd[1]: Starting Networking for netctl profile wlp3s0-tian...
Apr 29 18:31:33 ArchPad network[2167]: Starting network profile 'wlp3s0-tian'...
Apr 29 18:31:49 ArchPad network[2167]: WPA association/authentication failed for interface 'wlp3s0'
Apr 29 18:31:49 ArchPad network[2167]: Failed to bring the network up for profile 'wlp3s0-tian'
Apr 29 18:31:49 ArchPad systemd[1]: netctl@wlp3s0\x2dtian.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
Apr 29 18:31:49 ArchPad systemd[1]: Failed to start Networking for netctl profile wlp3s0-tian.
Apr 29 18:31:49 ArchPad systemd[1]: netctl@wlp3s0\x2dtian.service: Unit entered failed state.
Apr 29 18:31:49 ArchPad systemd[1]: netctl@wlp3s0\x2dtian.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
```

But while I use these command manually start `wpa_supplicant` and `dhcpcd`,
no problem occurs:

`` sudo ip link set wlp3s0 up
wpa_passphrase tian `sudo cat /etc/netctl/wlp3s0-tian  | grep Key | sed 's/=/ /' | awk '{print $2}'` | sudo wpa_supplicant -c /dev/stdin -D nl80211 -i wlp3s0 -B
sudo dhcpcd -4 --waitip -L wlp3s0 ``

And if the systemd runs `wpa_supplicant`, it just add `-P` and `-q`.

So, I wander why systemd cannot start my wifi correctly and it is boring to start and restart my wifi manually every time.